# how to plot contourf for irregular data

Tags: python

I have a set of irregular data. Here are the coordinates I have :
`([0,0], [17,0], [0,17], [-17, 0], [0, -17])`. Data for `[17, 17], [-17,-17], [-17, 17] and [17, -17]` are not available. I would like to perform `contourf` with `myplotlib` for this grid. How can I deal with such a grid? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you share the code you have attempted?

Comment: With "irregular" I suppose you refer to the absence of data in the corners? Or do you mean to say that the XY coordinates are irregularly spaced?

Comment: Yes, I mean the absence of the data in the corners. And more generally missing of some data so the grid is not rectangular.

Comment: I can not provide any code because it is clear that contourf of tricontourf requires rectangular grid which I do not have. So I do not know how to pass my grid and values on it.